# Prove by method of finite induction for n belongs to Natural Numbers

Tags: induction

I cannot prove the third step; I don't understand how to go ahead!
[image: Can't go ahead of this]

Comment: Why the donwvotes can someone please answer?

Comment: Are you saying that you've already completed the third step? If so, you're done! The combination of those statements is enough to prove the theorem.

Comment: @AndrewStelzer no I have to prove the third step

Comment: I think the downvotes come from people who dislike the picture, and would've liked it typeset within the site itself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you familiar with the angle sum formulas for $\sin$ and $\cos$? For reference, $$\sin(a+b)=\sin(a)\cos(b)+\cos(a)\sin(b)$$
$$\cos(a+b)=\cos(a)\cos(b)-\sin(a)\sin(b)$$
You should be able to apply these rules to the right hand side of the statement in part c) in order to write it in terms of your base case and assumption in part b).

Comment: I get z^m = (isin m ø - z^m )cos - isin m ø - sinø .... How do I go ahead?

Comment: I get z^(m+1)= (isin m ø - z^m )cos - isin m ø - sinø .... How do I go ahead?

Comment: Got it thanks sir